# Is there a way to catch when vsprintf is called with the wrong type or wrong number of arguments?

Tags: php, printf

vsprintf() happily ignores the following mistakes:

```
// I'd like to tell me that there are too many arguments.
vsprintf("%d", 1, 2); 

// this string gets converted to 0! instead of throwing an exception
vsprintf("%d", "nonsense");
```

Is there any way I can catch these types of errors?

**Edit**

Perhaps my question wasn't very clear. I need to actually try/catch such errors as I use vsprintf inside a simple MySQLi wrapper so users might do something like:

```
DB::select("*")->from("User")->where("salary=%d %s",$bogus_string)
```

In this case I need to tell them in a meaningful way that 1) %d expected an integer 2) that I don't know what to do with the extraneous %s 3) I need to support production environments as well.

Comment: The second one cannot be caught. It's native PHP behavior: types joggling.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, see the further explanation. Not sure why the question was down voted though, a meaningful comment with the down vote is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

An absolutely valid question that I find no reason for down-voting... I ran into the same issue when creating a message log that includes :

- A string in vsprintf format
- An array of parameters
- A list of recipients
- A sender
- A type

In the message log constructor, I perform various checks, as some of those attributes can be null, and some combinations don't make sense (e.g. a 'chat' type with no sender, a list of recipients with the sender in it, etc)

Since I needed to test whether or not the proper number & types of arguments were passed to vsprintf, I ended calling vsprintf inside my constructor in a `try...catch` statement, and reporting on the exception that was caught.

This is not perfect, as ideally I don't need to "render" the message yet at the time of construction, but it cover most of my needs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may write something like this:

```
try {

  if (!preg_match('~[^%]%[bcdeEfFgGosuxX]~', $msg)) { throw new Exception('There are no sprintf() sequences in `haystack`'); }

  $msg = vsprintf($msg, $data);

  if (preg_match('~[^%]%[bcdeEfFgGosuxX]~', $msg)) { throw new Exception('There are sprintf() sequences in `haystack` - it means you\'re passing less or too many parameters than needed...'); }

} catch (Exception $e) {}
```

Please be aware that Regex is getting a lot CPU & RAM on big data

Comment: Also you can write function with preg_replace_callback() that replaces only vars you passed to function, another ones left without changes